# Why does overloading operator< for std::tuple not seem to work in priority_queue?

Tags: c++, stdtuple

Here is the MWE:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

bool operator<(tuple<int, int, int> lhs, tuple<int, int, int> rhs)
{
    return get<1>(lhs) < get<1>(rhs);
}

int main()
{
    priority_queue<tuple<int, int, int>> q;
    q.push(make_tuple(2, 5, 3));
    q.push(make_tuple(2, 3, 3));
    cout << get<1>(q.top());
    return 0;
}
```

The weird part is that whether I type `<` or `>` in the sentence `return get<1>(lhs) < get<1>(rhs);`, the output is always `5`. Why does this happen?

Comment: My best guess: it's using the default comparison operator for generic tuples. Probably because your operator is not in the std namespace. Try implementing a custom comparator that explicitly calls your operator.

Comment: See dupe: [Why does `std::priority_queue` return largest elements first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44750632/why-does-stdpriority-queue-return-largest-elements-first-but-use-stdless)

Comment: @JasonLiam it's not a dupe of that

Comment: You should probably not use `std::tuple` for things like this, since it comes with it's own comparison operator overloads. You should probably define your own `struct` with three `int`s... That way you can also give your members proper names. But if you really want this, you can specify the compare function for the `priority_queue`, e.g. `auto cmp = [](tuple<int, int, int> lhs, tuple<int, int, int> rhs) { return get<1>(lhs) < get<1>(rhs); };` and `priority_queue<tuple<int, int, int>,std::vector<tuple<int, int, int>>, decltype(cmp)> q;`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your overload of `operator<` is not selected because it's in a different namespace than both `std::priority_queue` and `std::tuple`. It's not in the candidate set, so it is never even considered as an overload candidate.

The search for a suitable overload happens in the namespace where the operator is called from, which is the namespace `priority_queue` lives in, i.e. `std`. [Argument-dependent lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) causes an additional search in the namespaces of the arguments, but because `tuple` is also in the `std` namespace, that doesn't help either. There is no reason for the compiler to ever consider the global namespace at all.

Instead, the [standard library's definition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/operator_cmp) of `std::operator<` for tuples is used. You can see that if you put your own implementation in a `namespace std` block:

```
// !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
// BAD SOLUTION, DO NOT USE
// !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

namespace std {
bool operator<(tuple<int, int, int> lhs, tuple<int, int, int> rhs)
{
    return get<1>(lhs) > get<1>(rhs); // Changed to > so we can see the difference.
}
}
```

Now the output is `3`. Your operator is now considered *and* takes precedence over the default one, because non-template functions come before template functions.

But it is **forbidden by the standard** to put your own code into `namespace std` (with [some small exceptions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std)), so what to do? The solution is to pass a comparator functor explicitly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

struct element_1_greater {
    bool operator()(tuple<int, int, int> lhs, tuple<int, int, int> rhs)
    {
        return get<1>(lhs) > get<1>(rhs);
    }
};

int main()
{
    priority_queue<tuple<int, int, int>, vector<tuple<int, int, int>>, element_1_greater> q;
    q.push(make_tuple(2,5,3));
    q.push(make_tuple(2,3,3));
    cout << get<1>(q.top()) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Notice that we need to pass the second argument to `priority_queue` as well; you can shorten this with a `typedef` or `using` declaration of course.

Comment: Yeah, I showed the custom comparator template argument in the comments. I put it there, because it's not an actual answer to the question. And "best solution" is debatable. In my experience it's often "better" to replace the tuple by a custom class, if only to have proper names for the members.

Answer (score 2):

`std::tuple` is in the namespace `std`, the compiler looks for an overloaded [`operator<` (3)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/operator_cmp) in the namespace `std` until C++20 and [`operator<=>` (7)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/operator_cmp) also in the namespace `std` since C++20. The one of the global namespace is not considered while searching due to the argument dependent name lookup rules.

The fix:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

bool operator<(tuple<int, int, int> lhs, tuple<int, int, int> rhs)
{
    return get<1>(lhs) > get<1>(rhs);
}

int main()
{
    using T = tuple<int, int, int>;
    priority_queue<T, vector<T>, bool(*)(T, T)> q(::operator<);
    q.push(make_tuple(2,5,3));
    q.push(make_tuple(2,3,3));
    cout << get<1>(q.top());
    return 0;
}
// Outputs: 3
```

Comment: This answer would be better if it explained _why_ it's a closer match, with reference to the C++ overloading rules. In particular, non-template functions typically take precedence over template functions like the `std` implementation of `operator<`, so why isn't that happening here?

Comment: Not a closer match, just OP's overload is even not in overload set with ADL.

Comment: @Jarod42 Why not? Why wouldn't ADL apply here?

Comment: @Thomas: ADL applies, `priority_queue` ans `tuple` bring namespace std, `int` brings no namespaces (and not the global namespace); So only `std::operator<` are found.

Comment: @Jarod42 does adl take precedence? Because since the custom operator is defined in the global namespace I would have expected it to be found/considered as well.